# Api Exception filters for autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I have Configured webapi with `IAutofacExceptionFilter` to get the Exception Details. registered all the things in autofac.config

```
HttpConfiguration config = ServiceConfig.Initialize(new ConfigBuilder(options, (configuration, builder) =>
{  
       builder.RegisterType<ErrorLoggingExceptionFilter>()
       .AsWebApiExceptionFilterFor<BaseController>()
       .InstancePerApiRequest();

       builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
       //builder.RegisterType<ErrorLoggingExceptionFilter>()
       //.AsWebApiExceptionFilterFor<BaseController>().SingleInstance();

       builder.OverrideWebApiActionFilterFor<BaseController>();
       builder.RegisterSource(
       new AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource(t => 
         !(t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Meta<>))
    ));
}
 var serviceResolver = (AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver)config.DependencyResolver;
```

but it gives me error like

> The `AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver` must be configured as the dependency resolver for Web API before the `AutofacControllerConfigurationAttribute` can resolve services from the container for a controller type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something like this to make `AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver` your default Web API dependency resolver :

```
// Set the dependency resolver to be Autofac.
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
var container = builder.Build();
config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```

See [Autofac documentation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#quick-start) for more info.

Comment: I have using mobile services. so resolve the Dependency once the builder was build. and getting this error